# Firebird Error while i trying to select from one Table

Tags: firebird

```
Engine Message: 
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
Error writing data to the connection.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I use Flame Robin as a client and Firebird 1.5.... 
Any suggestions please

Comment: Firebird 1.5 is veeeery old, why use it? You most probably make the server crash badly by triggering some its old bug.
 ~~~ 1) show the query and show the table declaration (AKA Schema, DDL)
 ~~~ 2) read last messages in `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_1_5\firebird.log`

Comment: I strongly suggest you upgrade to either Firebird 2.5 or 3.0 (but don't do it without considering the changes documented in the release notes of 2.0, 2.1, 2.5 and 3.0), there have been several security bugs that allowed a malformed packet to crash Firebird server in the past, as Firebird 1.5 has been out-of-support for eight years, there are no fixes for that version. As to your specific problem, it could be anything from a crashed server process, to a firewall that closes the connection for some reason.

Comment: there were a lot breaking changes that implement SQL standard over Interbase legacy in FB2....

Comment: Please post relevant DDL, the actual query you used and the last messages in the firebird log file.